# Variables in makefile prerequisites

Tags: makefile, prerequisites

Is it possible to use makefile variables in prerequisites?  My example below is a little backward, but should demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
objects_subsystem1 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss1/*.c))
objects_subsystem2 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss2/*.c))

all : subsystem1.elf subsystem2.elf

%.elf : $(objects_%)
    $(LD) $< -o $@
```

EDIT:
I'm using GNU Make 3.80 so unfortunately SECONDEXPANSION is not available!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you're using GNUMake:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.elf : $$(objects_%)
    $(LD) $< -o $@
```

**EDIT:**

As @bobbogo points out, there is a solution that does not require `.SECONDEXPANSION`. First, we spell out the rules:

```
objects_subsystem1 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss1/*.c))
objects_subsystem2 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss2/*.c))
objects_subsystem3 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss3/*.c))

all : subsystem1.elf subsystem2.elf subsystem3.elf

subsystem1.elf : $(objects_subsystem1)
    $(LD) $< -o $@
subsystem2.elf : $(objects_subsystem2)
    $(LD) $< -o $@
subsystem3.elf : $(objects_subsystem3)
    $(LD) $< -o $@
```

Then we rearrange things a little:

```
objects_subsystem1 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss1/*.c))
all : subsystem1.elf
subsystem1.elf : $(objects_subsystem1)
objects_subsystem2 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss2/*.c))
all : subsystem2.elf
subsystem2.elf : $(objects_subsystem2)
objects_subsystem3 := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss3/*.c))
all : subsystem3.elf
subsystem3.elf : $(objects_subsystem3)

%.elf :
    $(LD) $< -o $@
```

Then we use the `eval` function:

```
define RULE_TEMPLATE
objects_subsystem$(1) := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss$(1)/*.c))
all : subsystem$(1).elf
subsystem$(1).elf : $$(objects_subsystem$(1))
endef

$(eval $(call RULE_TEMPLATE,1))
$(eval $(call RULE_TEMPLATE,2))
$(eval $(call RULE_TEMPLATE,3))

%.elf :
    $(LD) $< -o $@
```

Then finish up with a loop (if it's worth it):

```
define RULE_TEMPLATE
objects_subsystem$(1) := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard ../src/ss$(1)/*.c))
all : subsystem$(1).elf
subsystem$(1).elf : $$(objects_subsystem$(1))
endef

SUBSYSTEMS := 1 2 3 # this can be made automatic...

$(foreach sys,$(SUBSYSTEMS),$(eval $(call RULE_TEMPLATE,$(sys))))

%.elf :
    $(LD) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Just the pointer I was looking for.  Thanks for providing the answer.

Comment: Whilst this answer is good it doesn't work in my old version of GNU Make 3.80.  Appears to be available from 3.81 onwards: http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/whats-new-gnu-make-381  Unfortunately my make program is part of a supplier tool chain and not something I can update :(

Comment: Then a simple `subsystem1.elf: ${objects_subsystem1}` on a line by itself should suffice. If you need a bunch of these then stick it in a loop with `$(eval...)`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate bobbogo.  Would each 'one liner' also need the LD command?  Yes, I do have a growing bunch of these so want to automate as much as possible.

Comment: That's fantastic Beta.  Thanks for providing such a detailed response :)